# Getting error message while sending an email attachment from python notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, databricks

I am reading the data (using  Python not pyspark) from snowflake and I need to attach the output data as attachemnt(csv file) and and send email.

getting below error message  TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
at code   fp = open(message)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

import numpy as np
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.tsa as tsa
import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def main(days=31, offset=0):
   
    indices = ['country', 'statenumber', 'REPORTINGCOUNTRYSITENAME']
    bound_start = date.today() - pd.offsets.Week(offset, weekday=4)  
    bound_end = bound_start + timedelta(days=days)  

    data = query_snowflake()

    result = older_model(data, bound_start, bound_end)
    print(result)
        
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 
    mail_from = 'ABCD@company.com'
    mail_to = 'ABCD@company.com'
    gmailUser="admin@company"
    gmailPassword="abcd1234"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = mail_from
    msg['To'] = mail_to
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject that is meaningful to the recipient"
    mail_body = "Something happened in your databricks notebook"
    message = result.to_csv('mydata')
    fp = open(message)
    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    msg.attach(attachment)

 
    try:
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.starttls()
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)
        mailServer.send_message(msg)
        mailServer.close()
        print('Email sent!')
    except:
        print('Something went wrong...')
```

Answer (score 0):

> result.to_csv('mydata')

must return NoneType in this case,
try to output variable before

> fp = open(message)